# Which database vendors support Aggregate Rank() function?

Tags: oracle, aggregate-functions, rdbms, rank

I have looked at a few database vendors and so far only Oracle seems to support the rank() function in both contexts; Analytical & Aggregate.

Here is the link to their doc: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions123.htm

I have looked at mySQL, Snowflake, e.t.c but they all seem to be only supporting the analytical rank(). 
Has anyone used rank in aggregate context with any other RDBMS or is it usually a work around?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, at the moment (April 2018) only two databases have implemented this function as aggregate:

**Oracle** --> demo --> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/74fa70/2

```
SELECT rank( 2 ) within group (order by x) as rank_x FROM qwe;

SELECT rank( 2 ) within group (order by y) as rank_y FROM qwe;

SELECT rank( 2, 7 ) within group (order by x,y)  as rank_x_y FROM qwe;

| RANK_X |
|--------|
|      5 |

| RANK_Y |
|--------|
|      2 |

| RANK_X_Y |
|----------|
|        7 |
```

---

**PostgreSQL** --> demo --> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/74fa7/5

```
SELECT rank( 2 ) within group (order by x) as rank_x FROM qwe;

SELECT rank( 2 ) within group (order by y) as rank_y FROM qwe;

SELECT rank( 2, 7 ) within group (order by x,y)  as rank_x_y FROM qwe;

| RANK_X |
|--------|
|      5 |

| RANK_Y |
|--------|
|      2 |

| RANK_X_Y |
|----------|
|        7 |
```

---

The analytical version `rank() over`, in addition to Oracle and PostgreSQL,  has also been implemented in SQL-Server, DB2, MySql (will be in upcoming version).

---

These two demos are based on the below sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE qwe(
  x int, y int
 );

insert into qwe values(1,1);
insert into qwe values(1,2);
insert into qwe values(1,3);
insert into qwe values(1,4);
insert into qwe values(2,5);
insert into qwe values(2,6);
insert into qwe values(3,7);
```